# Create a New Column by evaluating multiple columns

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data.frame `dt_info` that looks like the following:

```
date       col_1     col_2    col_3  ... col_100
d/m/y       info1     n/a      n/a   ...  n/a
d/m/y       n/a       n/a     info2  ...  n/a
d/m/y       n/a       n/a       n/a  ...  infon
```

The output I'm looking for should be like this:

```
date       col_1     col_2    col_3  ... col_100    new_col
d/m/y       info1     n/a      n/a   ...  n/a         info1
d/m/y       n/a       n/a     info2  ...  n/a         info2
d/m/y       n/a       n/a       n/a  ...  infon       infon
```

I'm using this code line

```
dt_info$new_col <- apply(dt_info[2],1, function(x){
ifelse(x != "n/a", x, "")})
```

That kinda do what I want but I have two issues
I'm not able to go do it for each column using `[1:n]`
If I change Manually the `[]` index and run the code, the whole column got replaced.

What am I lacking in my script?
Is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: note that n/a is Character not NA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value `n/a` is really the `NA` value for R, then you may use `coalesce` here from the `dplyr` library

```
library(dplyr_
dt_info$new_col <- coalesce(dt_info$col_1, dt_info$col_2, ..., dt_info$col_100)
```

If the `n/a` value be literally there, then you may first convert it to `NA`, and then use `coalesce` as above:

```
dt_info[dt_info == "n/a"] = NA
dt_info$new_col <- coalesce(dt_info$col_1, dt_info$col_2, ..., dt_info$col_100)
```

Comment: The problem in his code is that his output from the `ifelse` call is a vector of `length > 1`, but he tries to assign it to a vector of  `length = 1`. That is why he gets his entire column overwritten.

Comment: This worked fine for me, but I wasn't able to pass (dt_info$col_1, dt_info$col_2, ..., dt_info$col_100) in a variable like cols <- c("dt_info$col_1", "dt_info$col_2", ..., "dt_info$col_100"). I was trying save in a variable de cols because this could be more or less in a future script.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, the `apply` function takes a `MARGIN =` argument, when you set it to `MARGIN = 1` you can apply your functions to rows - so you do not need to pass your indices. What happens when you use `ifelse` is that you get a vector of `length = ncol(dt_info)` which you try to assign to an entry of `length = 1`. To avoid it you need to collpase it into a single value -  the `name` or `""` :

```
    dt_info$new_col <- apply(dt_info,1, function(x){
                                                    if(sum(x != "n/a")){
                                                        x[x!="n/a"]
                                                    }else{
                                                     ""
                                                    }})
```

Comment: Using `apply` in row mode like this is generally not desirable or optimal.

Comment: I just provided a possible solution, never have I claimed to be optimal. You are welcome to provide a more optimal solution if you have one, I will also be happy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution uisng `tidyverse` and `gsub`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1<- df %>% 
  dplyr::select(-date) %>%
  tidyr::unite(newCol,everything(),remove = FALSE) %>%  # concat all columsn except date
  dplyr::mutate(newCol=gsub("n/a","",newCol), # removing n/a as text
                newCol=gsub("\\_","\\1",newCol)) %>% # removing all '_' cretaed during concat 
  dplyr::bind_cols(date=df$date) # merging date column back

df1

   newCol col_1 col_2 col_3 col_100  date
1:  info1 info1   n/a   n/a     n/a d/m/y
2:  info2   n/a   n/a info2     n/a d/m/y
3:  infon   n/a   n/a   n/a   infon d/m/y
```

Answer (score 0):

You may easily subset your data row-wise to the elements that are not (`!`) `%in%` `"n/a"`.

```
dt_info$new_col <- apply(dt_info[-1], 1, function(x) x[!x %in% "n/a"])
dt_info
#    date col_1 col_2 col_3 col_100 new_col
# 1 d/m/y info1   n/a   n/a     n/a   info1
# 2 d/m/y   n/a   n/a info2     n/a   info2
# 3 d/m/y   n/a   n/a   n/a   infon   infon
```

**However**, the `"n/a"` strings are a bit strange; you could make them "true" `NA`,

```
dt_info2 <- as.data.frame(lapply(dt_info, function(x) {x[x %in% "n/a"] <- NA;x}))
```

and use `na.omit` then, which is much more efficient.

```
dt_info2$new_col <- apply(dt_info2[-1], 1, na.omit)
#    date col_1 col_2 col_3 col_100 new_col
# 1 d/m/y info1  <NA>  <NA>    <NA>   info1
# 2 d/m/y  <NA>  <NA> info2    <NA>   info2
# 3 d/m/y  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>   infon   infon
```

---

*Data:*

```
dt_info <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="date       col_1     col_2    col_3   col_100
'd/m/y'       info1     'n/a'      'n/a'     'n/a'
'd/m/y'       'n/a'       'n/a'     info2    'n/a'
'd/m/y'       'n/a'       'n/a'       'n/a'    infon")
```

Answer (score 0):

A vectorized way using `max.col` :

```
cols <- grep('col', names(dt_info))
dt_info$new_col <- dt_info[cols][cbind(1:nrow(dt_info), 
                       max.col(dt_info[cols] != 'n/a', ties.method = 'first'))]
```

Assuming you'll always have a non-`'n/a'` value in a row this will return the first one of it.